# Como puedo mostrar un div en una ruta que contiene id con Angular?

Tags: angular, router

en **Angular** saben como puedo mostrar un `div` **solamente** en una ruta que contenga `id` ?

```
const rutas: Routes = [
    {path: 'prod/detail/:productid', component: ProductDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];
```

por ejemplo si la ruta es `http://localhost:4200/prod/detail/5ea51e2cfb986c7d84282d41`

que me recomendarían ? Trate con router pero no pude realizarlo

Quiero mostrar un **boton** de regreso solamente en mi ruta de detalle, esto es el `header`

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>
        <a *ngIf="router.url === '/prod/detail/:productid'" id="poke" routerLink="/">
            <img [src]="arrow"
        />
        </a>
    </span>
    <span  ...

</mat-toolbar>


constructor(
    public route: Router,
    private autService: AutService
  ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo de la siguiente manera:

En tu `header.component.ts` agregas la siguiente logica.

```
 mostrarBotonRegresar = false


  constructor(private router: Router, public location: Location) {
    router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(e.url);

        this.mostrarBotonRegresar = e.url.includes('detalle/')
      }
    });
  }
```

Y en el `header.component.html` tu botón:

```
<button 

(click)='location.back()'
*ngIf="mostrarBotonRegresar"
>Retornar porque es detalle</button>
```

Estas son las importaciones que ocupas:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

Ten cuidado con la importacion de `Location`. Hay otro que no se ocupa importar y da error.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6lwk7)